# The editing of the file config.yml through the interface. Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question, is it possible to edit some file config.yml through the web interface? I made two methods `edit` and `update` in controller `SettingsController`. But how do I implement a form with data? What advice can have? Correctly organized routes?

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resource :settings, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

Comment: While it might be technically possible, editing files directly through some web interface sounds like a bad/insecure idea.

It sounds like you're a Rails beginner. Implementing forms in Rails is a trivial task that you can learn from any book or online tutorial. As far as books go, I recommend Agile Web Development With Rails.